# apply a function on two ndarrays's corresponding rows at once(without for loop)

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to apply one function to two ndarray's corresponding elements at once without using a for loop. Let's say I have the following two ndarrays `x` and `y` and a function `foo` that takes in two 1d-arrays and compute the `beta`.
The end result I want is to compute `beta00 = foo(x[0, 0],y[0])`, `beta01 = foo(x[0, 1], y[1])`, `beta10 = foo(x[1, 0],y[0])`, `beta11 = foo(x[1, 1], y[1])` and yield a expected result of

```
   [[beta00, beta01],
    [beta10, beta11]]
```

I have been looking into vectorize function and apply function, but still don't have a solution. Could someone help me on this? Many thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
              [[2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5]]])
y = np.array([[-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1], [-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1]])

def foo(x,y):
    A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(x.shape)]).T
    return np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0][0]
```

Comment: you can redefine your foo as def foo(x) where x will be a tuple and then use map(foo, zip(x,y))

Comment: Your code will be clearer if you use the common 2d numpy indexing, `a[0,0]` instead of `a[0][0]`.  And `x.shape[0]` rather than `len(x)`.  In other words make it very clear where you have 1d, 2d, etc arrays. That said, the key to real vectorization is to write `foo` so it accepts multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want

```
beta[i,j] = foo(x[i,j,:], y[j,:])
```

Where `foo` takes 2 1d arrays, and returns a scalar.  The explicit `:` make it clear that we are using 3 and 2 arrays.

`np.vectorize` will not help because its function must accept scalars, not arrays.  And - it is not a speed solution.  It just as nice way of enabling broadcasting, handling inputs with a variety of dimensions.

There looping wrappers like `apply_along(over)_axis`, but they are still Python level loops.  The key to any real speedup will be reworking the `foo` so it operates on 2 or 3d arrays, not just 1d ones.  But that may be more work than it's worth, or even impossible.

So for reference, any alternative must match:

```
beta = np.zeros(x.shape[:2])
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        beta[i,j] = foo(x[i,j,:],y[j,:])
```

An alternative way of generating the multidimensional indexes is:

```
for i,j in np.ndindex(x.shape[:2]):
    beta[i,j] = foo(x[i,j,:], y[j,:])
```

but it's not a time saver.

Look into whether `foo` can be written to accept a 2d `y`,

```
  foo(x[i,j,:], y[None,j,:])
```

aiming eventually to be able to do:

```
  beta = foo1(x, y[None,:])
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you. But just for the purpose of learning numpy, how should I use `apply_along(over)_axis` here. I looked at the doc but I am still a little bit confused.

Comment: I've answered questions about the `apply...` functions, but haven't used them for my own code.  They may not fit this case, since they are designed to work with just one input array, and don't coordinate iteration over 2.